# Android Opengl Es draw line doesn't work properly on Adreno GPUs

Tags: android, gpu, opengl-es-1.1

Hi I'm working on Android opengl es 1.1. When I draw line, it works properly on Galaxy S6 which has Mali-T760  gpu. But when I run same program on Nexus 4(Adreno 320) and ODG R7(Adreno 420), program can't change line width and can't draw line. Only draw part of line strip. I think it is about Adreno GPUs but I'm not sure. If it is so is there any solution. Need help. Thanks.[Nexus 4 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMgoU.png)

[S6 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3CkA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem's source. Enabling GL_LINE_SMOOTH is cause problem in Adreno GPUs.